# How do I create splash screen that works on all screen dimensions?

Tags: android, layout

I have the design of the screen. for example - my design has two layers (dark and light green colors) and text or logo.

[image]

How I can to create this logo for all screens? I think, that ONE big image (and copies for hdpi mdpi etc, because this application can be used on 320x240 screen and on the google nexus with retina-style display) - is no good idea. How can I to create one background, one rectangle and logo layers?

Comment: currently - background is image.

Comment: So the logo is not a individual image, but it's part of the background image?

Comment: Goot, yes, this is only background. I can to use the "layer-list", but lines... I don't understand how to implement this lines for all screens. they sometimes overlap

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a look at LayerDrawable :

> A `Drawable` that manages an array of other `Drawables`. These are drawn
>   in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on
>   top.
>
> It can be defined in an XML file with the `<layer-list`> element. Each
>   Drawable in the layer is defined in a nested `<item>`.

[More details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)

[Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to fill the screen with your rectangular drawable?